# My list keeps appearing empty after using binary serialization, however is fine if deserialized

Tags: c#, serialization

I am experiencing an issue where when I create a record and serialize it, accessing it immediately after, List _log; has a 0 count and no items. However, upon restart of my application (because the records are only loaded on startup) accessing the same record again does bring back the items that were contained in the list.

The List in question is being used by `ItemsSource` binding to a `DataGrid` if that will help any.

Record code below:

```
[Serializable]
public class Record
{
    private List<LogEntry> _log;
    private Account _account;
    private string _callReason;
    private string _customerName;
    private DateTime _timeStamp;

    public List<LogEntry> Log { get { return _log; } }
    public Account Account { get { return _account; } }
    public string CallReason { get { return _callReason; } }
    public string CustomerName { get { return _customerName; } }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get { return _timeStamp; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// A record for interactions.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="account"></param>
    /// <param name="customerName"></param>
    /// <param name="callReason"></param>
    /// <param name="log"></param>
    public Record(Account account, string customerName, string callReason, List<LogEntry> log)
    {
        _account = account;
        _customerName = customerName;
        _callReason = callReason;
        _log = log;
        _timeStamp = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class RecordKeeper
{
    public List<Record> Records { get; protected set; }

    public RecordKeeper()
    {
        Records = new List<Record>();
        LoadUsers();
    }

    public void SaveUsers()  // Save users data
    {
        try
        {
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            var file = new FileStream("Records.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            bf.Serialize(file, Records.ToArray());
            file.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Exception(ex, "Error while saving user data.");
        }
    }

    private void LoadUsers()  // Load users data
    {
        try
        {
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            var file = new FileStream("Records.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var infos = (Record[])bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            Records = infos.ToList();
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

## Edit

I discovered where my issue occurs but I do not understand why this happens. I clear the listed being used by the `DataGrid` AFTER creating and serializing the record, however the value in the Record gets modified as well.

```
    public MainWindow(RecordKeeper recordKeeper)
    {
        _recordKeeper = recordKeeper;
        _logEntries = new List<LogEntry>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<LogEntry> _logEntries;
    public List<LogEntry> LogEntries { get { return _logEntries; } }

    private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!DependencyObjectIsValid(this)) return;
        var account = new Account(long.Parse(AccountNumberBox.Text));
        List<LogEntry> recordLog = LogEntries; // count is 3
        var record = new Record(account, CustomerName.Text, CallReason.Text, recordLog); 
        RecordKeeper.Records.Add(record); 
        RecordKeeper.SaveUsers(); // record.Log.Count is still 3
        AccountNumberBox.Text = "";
        CustomerName.Text = "";
        CallReason.Text = "";
        LogMessage.Text = "";
        LogEntries.Clear(); // record.Log.Count is 0, shouldn't the instance be separate and immutable at this point in execution?
        LogGrid.Items.Refresh();
        RecordGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

## Edit 2

Creating a new list in the record seemed to do the trick for me

replacing

```
`_log = log; `
```

with

```
`_log = new List<LogEntry>();
foreach (LogEntry entry in log)
{
    _log.Add(entry);
}`
```

In Record's constructor. Not sure it's the best practice though to achieve this.

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant

## Edit 3

```
List<LogEntry> recordLog = new List<LogEntry>(LogEntries);
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but it works on my machine. Please add the missing code which makes it a SSCCE. Perhaps I do something different than you when initializing the variables. Other than than: quite good first question including so much code. Welcome on SO!

Comment: No, the "instance" is not separate and not immutable.  If Record.Log should not be cleared then it needs to create its own list.

Comment: would

`   _log = new List<LogEntry>();
   foreach (LogEntry entry in log)
   {
    _log.Add(entry);
   }
`
work for this?

Comment: Instead of the above I did `List<LogEntry> recordLog = new List<LogEntry>(LogEntries);`